# Get state and update state in a non react component in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I am working on a nextjs project where i have a helpers folder in level with pages folder.

I have a ts file inside helpers folder and here i want to get the latest state and update state depending on the latest state

This is how im getting the state

```
store().getState()
```

where store is imported from store.js

Im updating state depending on the previous state

```
    const state = store().getState()

    if(!state.currentUser){   // here im checking if state has currentUser
        store().dispatch(Action)  // here im calling action which will update the state
    }

    do further operations
```

The problem here is I'm not getting the updated state from `store().getState()` after updating the state. Is the way I'm managing things correctly? How to get the updated state?

`*EDIT* : Im sending a helper function as a prop to many if my page components. Now that i dont want to touch this , i somehow want to get the updated state and dispatch actions based on the state itself. Note that the hepler function is not a functional component`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this store you're using isn't part of React, so React doesn't know when the data changes. You have to create a way to let React know that the data changes so it could then rerender your component or trigger an action.
Does your store offer a way to subscribe to changes? If so you can do something like this in your component (assuming you're using hooks):

**Edit: Reusable hook way:**

```
export const useStore = () => {
    const [storeState, setStoreState] = useState(store().getState());
    useEffect(() => {
      const subscribeFunc = (newState) => setStoreState(newState));
      store().subscribe(subscribeFunc);
      return () => {
        store().unsubscribe(subscribeFunc);
      }
    }, [])

    return [storeState, store().dispatch]
  }
```

then in your component

```
const [storeState, dispatch] = useStore();

// listen to changes of the currentUser and fire actions accordingly
useEffect(() => {
  if (!storeState.currentUser) {
    dispatch(Action)
  }
}, [storeState.currentUser])
```

**Initial way:**

```
// sync the store state with React state
const [storeState, setStoreState] = useState(store().getState());
useEffect(() => {
  const subscribeFunc = (newState) => setStoreState(newState));
  store().subscribe(subscribeFunc);
  return () => {
    store().unsubscribe(subscribeFunc);
  }
}, [])

// listen to changes of the currentUser and fire actions accordingly
useEffect(() => {
  if (!storeState.currentUser) {
    store().dispatch(Action)
  }
}, [storeState.currentUser])
```

By setting the state in the component on change, React now knows that data changed and will act accordingly.

This is a very local approach to explain the concept, but it would obviously be better to create a reusable hook to use throughout your app for any store.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. I Will try this out
Can u create a reusable hook where I can get the updated state and can dispatch actions in it?

Comment: @VijayThomas sure, I updated my answer. It's basically the same code but it's moved into a hook you can use in other components as well.

Comment: Im not able to use hooks just as u did. Its throwing an error `Can be used only inside functional components` @yts

Comment: I'm passing a helper function as a prop to my pages component. In this helper function i want to get updated state and dispatch actions depending on the conditions. Pls feel free if u need more data